# Angular2 - ng2-completer bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to implement **ng2-completer** component in my **Angular2** application.

The conponent works properly but the style of the search textbox is flat...
I want to have the same style of bootstrap components, like textbox for example.

## This is the code:

```
<ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [datasource]="searchData" [minSearchLength]="0" (selected)="onSelected($event)"></ng2-completer>
```

## This is the rendered control:

[image: rendered control]

As you can see, the list of color is ok but the input where the user write the value to search is completely flat...

How can I move to fix the problem ?

Basically I just want to set it like the field "Titolo" on the right.

Thanks

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `class="form-control"` to your textbox  ,`(class)="form-control"` in your case i guess

Answer (score 3):

Just add `[inputClass]="['form-control']"` in the selector.
For example:

`<ng2-completer [inputClass]="['form-control']" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [datasource]="searchData" [minSearchLength]="0" (selected)="onSelected($event)"></ng2-completer>`

Note: form-control is here a class of Bootstrap